# What is causing this firefox rendering bug?

Tags: css, firefox

On this website: http://escapology.com/ in firefox you can see an odd rendering bug as you scroll through the page. Certain elements will seem to not render the opacity correctly for a second or so and then be fine.

This hasn't always happened so I'm pretty sure it's avoidable but I cant figure out what exactly about the elements is causing it.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: I thought that might be the case yea. Unfortunately I dont know what the error is and so can't create a test case. Nevermind, the question can be close.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of answering a question thats here:

It turned out to be a bug relating to having multiple stacked objects with transforms. The solution was to fade them individually.